# Writing a function that take the sum of all numbers in and between two inputs

Tags: scheme, racket

Help! I'm trying to write a function that take the sum of all numbers in and between two inputs.

So far I have,

```
(define (sum-between x y)    
  (cond    
    [(= x y) x]
    [((- x y) 0) 0]
    [else (+ (+ x y) (sum-between (sub1 x) (sub1 y)))]))
```

This should return:

```
(check-expect (sum-between 0 2) 3)

(check-expect (sum-between -1 1) 0)

(check-expect (sum-between 7 7) 7)

(check-expect (sum-between 1 10) 55)
```

I'm not sure how to call the recursive case so it doesn't run in an infinite loop. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of a procedure is `(- x y)` going to make? By decrementing both `x` and `y` they will stay the same apart forever. By adding the sum of the first and last at each step you will add one of them `(- y x 1)` times too much. Tell me, how would you have done it on paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using built-in procedures? this is easier:

```
(define (sum-between x y)
  (apply + (range x (add1 y))))
```

But I guess you want to implement this from scratch. The main idea here is that one of the values must get closer and closer to the other, your error is that you're decrementing *both* of them. Try this instead:

```
(define (sum-between x y)    
  (cond    
    [(= x y) x]
    [else (+ x (sum-between (add1 x) y))]))
```

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes a lot of sense, thank you! I'm also trying to think about it as an accumulator function, but how would that work when I'm trying to take in two inputs as opposed to two lists?

Answer (score 0):

For/sum can also be used here:

```
(define (sum-between x y)
  (for/sum ((i (in-range x (add1 y))))
    i))

(sum-between 0 2)
(sum-between -1 1)
(sum-between 7 7)
(sum-between 1 10)
```

Output:

```
3
0
7
55
```